# What is the preferred way to allow api calls to my rust cli app

Tags: rust, command-line-interface

I am currently creating a cli app with the rust language. I was looking for a way to allow others to make plugins for my cli app, which users could download their plugins on their own and all them to plugins folder from where my cli app would look for plugin files and load then. What would be the best (if possible, the hacky way atleast) to load their binary rust/ source rust code in my binary cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible through dynamic loading. The exact details are OS-dependent, but the general idea is that there are OS calls to load binaries at runtime. It is, however, not possible to load the source code (at least, not at runtime).

There is [a crate](https://docs.rs/libloading/latest/libloading/) that will help you to reduce boilerplate of dynamic loading, and a [nice tutorial](https://adventures.michaelfbryan.com/posts/plugins-in-rust/) that will guide you step-by-step.